# The Last Reference in the output is not aligned properly while citing references of the research Paper using Bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, abbrvnat.bst

I'm attaching here the photo of the output of the References that I need in order. The problem is that the last Reference i.e 72th reference is not aligned as others as you clearly visible from the pic. I'm using a `.bst` file for defining rules of indentation and all and quite new to `LaTeX`.

[image]

Comment: Overleaf reports 22 error messages in your document. (You can find this number in the red box next to the "Recompile" button.) Have a look at those error messages and try to fix them. You can only expect your document to look OK once there are no more errors and as few warnings as possible. In this particular case I think the problem is due to a `_` in the title of reference 71 (Alom et al.). An unescaped `_` outside of math mode causes an error and starts math mode for the following text (that's why the remainder of the text is in italics without spaces).

Comment: Worked Perfectly. Thank you